# UNITY Implementing Multi-Window Setup for Windows UWP

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, uwp, multi-window

We're currently working on setting up a multi-window configuration for the Windows UWP target platform which unfortunately doesn't support Multi-window natively. Our project relies on Bluetooth code that's tailored specifically for Windows UWP, and unfortunately, it doesn't function properly when applied to other target platforms.

I've explored Unity's official documentation on multi-display setup (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html), but it appears that this method [isn't compatible with Windows UWP](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-support-multiple-displays-uwp.425926/#post-2753558), as discussed in this forum thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-support-multiple-displays-uwp.425926/. According to the responses there, there appear to be three potential solutions and we found 2 more that we're considering:

1. One option is to acquire an asset designed for multi-monitor support in Windows UWP, such as the one available at (https://www.republicofhandball.com/assets/) as posted here. However, this solution raises some concerns since it's not on the asset store and could be a bit shady.
2. Another possibility is to create our own secondary monitor functionality using Windows API, a more hands-on approach that would require quite some coding. as described [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-support-multiple-displays-uwp.425926/#post-2809811)
3. We're also contemplating the idea of rworking the Bluetooth code to function beyond the limitations of Windows UWP, potentially utilizing resources like https://github.com/adabru/BleWinrtDll or insights from this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/bluetooth-low-energy-on-windows-under-unity.509387/.
4. Another approach is using Nvidia Surround alongside viewport rect with dual cameras to simulate a second monitor.
5. Lastly, we're considering the option of developing a separate application specifically designed as a secondary monitor, which could communicate with the main application via UDP or another suitable method.

Given that the original thread dates back to 2013, there's a possibility that there's now a built-in solution available. Are we overlooking any potential approaches, or is there a recommended solution among these? Your insights would be greatly appreciated

Windows UWP doesn't support MultiWindow (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html)